# "Disallowed implicit conversion" when using Unicode strings with ADO parameterized queries: is there an "use any compatible" datatype?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ado

i am trying to parameterize a query, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO Trunions (Encabulator) VALUES (?)
```

This comes from a (sample) query:

```
INSERT INTO Trunions (Encabulator) VALUES ('Mẫrsểl vằnęs')
```

Now this query will run as long as the SQL Server database table contains some sort of compatible *string* column:

- `char(300)`
- `nchar(300)`
- `varchar(300)`
- `nvarchar(300)`
- `text`
- `ntext`
- `varchar(max)`
- `nvarchar(max)`

My *original*, **function** query will work. As soon as i parameterize the query the code no longer works:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Trunions (Encabulator) VALUES (?)";
String value = "Mẫrsểl vằnęs";

Command cmd = new Command();
...
cmd.Set_CommandText(sql);
cmd.Set_CommandType(adCmdText);
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("param1", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, -1, value);
cmd.Execute(out recordsAffected, Null, adCmdText | adExecuteNoRecords);
```

SQL Server complains that the parameter type doesn't match the column data type (i.e. the carpet doesn't match the curtains):

> Disallowed implicit conversion from data type %s to data type %s, table '%s', column '%s'.
>   Use the CONVERT function to run this query

In this example i tried to use the *"best"* (i.e. most inclusive data type): `adLongVarWChar`.

But what i need is the data type that can substitute for "any length unicode string".

What ADO parameter type will survive being put into an SQL Server string column?

**Note:**

- ADO, not ADO.net
- [That question is about the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726212/using-wrong-type-with-parameterized-query-causes-error) and open-ended hope for a solution. This question is about a generic "text" ado data type (Variant? Unknown? String?) (Yeah, what whoever changed my title to)

Comment: Dammit. i did more googling: *“Disallowed implicit conversion” when using Unicode strings with ADO parameterized.."* Hey, that's exactly what i'm experiencing!  Oh wait. :(

Comment: I hate it when that happens :-)